# has no exported member 'SubscriptionLike'

Tags: angular, ionic3, rxjs6

I have this code:

```
import { SubscriptionLike } from 'rxjs';
```

After importing this, I get the error

> node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'SubscriptionLike'.

Comment: what version of rxjs do you have?

Comment: thanx man. i got the ans later